# In-memory database vs RAM-disk

Tags: sqlite, in-memory-database

In SQLite, are there any differences in performance/features/reliability/... between:

1) an in-memory database: `rc = sqlite3_open("file::memory:", &db);`

2) a database on a RAM-disk?

The database must be accessible from multiple processes.

Regarding a SQLite database access by multiple processes, see [here](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5).

Comment: Can in-memory databases be shared between processes?

Comment: I read [it](http://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) again: "all database connections sharing the in-memory database need to be in the same process." So maybe the only way to have an in memory database usable by more than one process is to use a RAM-disk...

Comment: @Pietro Did you ever found the answer to this question? I'm interested in knowing if it's possible to use my SQLite off a RAM-disk.

Comment: @ElliotVargas: yes, it is possible to use a RAM-disk, since from the point of view of the DB it is not different from a hard-disk.

Answer (score 0):

Well doing queries in RAM disk is gonna be about 100 times faster than on HDD or 10 times faster than a SSD.  The biggest draw back is that if there is power problem your entire database can be wiped out.  Hope this helps!!!

Comment: My question is about the comparison of two possible ways to create a database in memory. Data loss is not an issue in my case.